# Debugging Send Error in Outlook 2013 (0x800CCC13)

Tags: email, windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2013

***Sending' reported error (0x800CCC13) : 'Cannot connect to the network. Verify your network connection or modem.'***

I have just upgraded to win10 and keep getting this error when trying to send email. Strangely, sending is confirmed as working when I 'Test Account Settings'.

The accounts are POP3.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- [Starting Outlook in safe mode "Outlook /safe"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/sending-reported-error-0x800ccc13-cannnot-connect/eda37e24-52a0-4665-8606-41482eade98a)
- Disabling all add ins
- [Unintegrating ESET from all emails related things](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2866&locale=en_US)
- Disabling firewall and disabling anti virus
- Deleting and recreating the email accounts
- [Creating a new Outlook profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/829918)
- [Creating a new Data File in Outlook](http://outlookpst.filerepairtool.net/blog/fix-outlook-2013-0x800ccc13-error)

I am running out of things to try - could anybody point me in the right direction to debug this?

Comment: Right click on the outlook shortcut that you are using & see if it set to run as an administrator ?

Comment: Thank you :)   I was just about to try that and by some magic got it working.  Now I am touching nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, and just after posting, this I sorted it.

I got the answer from here: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/cannot-send-after-windows-10-upgrade

Essentially you need to run sfc /scannow from the command prompt run under administrator access. Then restart. This repairs some files after upgrading to 10.